# How to pass value form App.js to DrawerContent.js in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

It want to show name in title from App.js to DrawerContent.js file in react native

**App.js**

```
<Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
  <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={MainTabScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen name='Support' component={SupportScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen name='Setting' component={SettingScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen name='Bookmark' component={BookmarkScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

**DrawerContent.js**

```
export function DrawerContent(props) {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <DrawerContentScrollView  {...props}>
                <View style={styles.drawerContent}>
                    <View style={styles.userInfoSection}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 15 }}>
                            <Avatar.Image
                                source={{
                                    uri: 'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/9f/a6/e6/9fa6e69f9d7dcd86989c8254f1483be8.jpg'
                                }}
                                size={50}
                            />
                            <View style={{ marginLeft: 15, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                                <Title style={styles.title}>name</Title>
                            </View>
                        </View>
              </View>
)
```

Comment: You can pass the name value by parameter by that way {...prop, ...appName}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**App.js**

```
try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('name', name);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
```

**DrawerContent.js**

```
   componentDidMount = async () => {
        try {
            const name = await AsyncStorage.getItem('name');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        componentDidMount();
    }, [])
```

You can use name anywhere in drawer content